# Obtain 384 bits from a 256bit MasterSecret

Tags: aes, key-derivation, gcm

I'm currently implementing, with `crypto++`, and AES tranmsission system, whose `key` is based on a previous `MasterSecret` of 256 bits (which has been expanded using PBKDF2).

This `MasterSecret` is then split into a `key` and an `iv`, to encrypt a message using `AES-GCM`.

I **must** work with AES-256, so my key must be 256-bit long. The iv for GCM is always 128-bit long.

So, briefly, I must extract from a 256-bit `MasterSecret` a 256-bit key and a 128-bit IV.

*How to do it ?*

I thought of taking the `MasterSecret` as the key, and then hashing the key to get then the iv of the desired length.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to obtain 384 bits from a 256 bit `MasterSecret` ?

Comment: Your method of IV generation seems dangerously flawed at first glance

Comment: @Richie - That's why I only *thought* of it ;)

Comment: Are you only using `MasterSecret` once? Then you can just use zero IV.

Comment: Yeah, it's just used to provide the keys for the AES. After that all communications will be encrypted with this key. Isn't it weaker for the security, to use a zero IV ?

Comment: I meant, will you use the key only once? Then zero IV is fine. If not, how are you deriving the IVs for subsequent messages?

Comment: Probably no. We will encrypt several messages... And must the `iv` be different from one message to another ? Must it only be used once ?

Comment: @EisenHeim, yes. GCM fails bad if you ever reuse an IV with the same key for two messages.

Comment: Is there a good reason to require exactly 128-bit IV? The default IV length for AES-GCM is 96 bits. Larger IV lengths than that will be (a bit) less efficient. See [NIST SP 800-38D](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf), section 8 for some discussion on choosing IV for GCM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need 384 bits of key material.  The IV for [GCM](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf) does not need to be secret, and may be chosen deterministically, e.g. as an incremental counter.  Thus, you only need 256 bits for the AES key, which you already have.

That said, if you *did* actually need more key material, you could use any standard [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to expand your 256 bits.  Since you presumably already have a 256-bit hash function available (for PBKDF2), I'd personally suggest using [HKDF-Expand](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869).  Since your master secret is already a pseudorandom bit string, you may safely skip the Extract part of HKDF; see §3.3 of the RFC.

<sup>(You *could* also request more bytes directly from PBKDF2, but this is [rather needlessly inefficient](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/derive-cipher-iv-and-cipher-key-using-pbkdf2-with-random-salt/26540#26540).  If you need more than one hash block of output from PBKDF2, it's better to combine it with a key-based KDF such as HKDF.  Technically, you could also use [a second PBKDF2 pass with an iteration count of 1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20960/pbkdf-vs-hkdf-for-pretty-long-key) instead of HKDF, but this feels a bit "untidy", as PBKDF2 was not really designed to be used like this.)</sup>

Comment: HKDF ins't implemented [yet](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Roadmap) in crypto++. I think I'll generate an `iv` every time I need one, without using bits of the `MasterSecret`.

Comment: That's a good choice. That said, [HKDF is pretty easy to implement yourself.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/generate-secure-password-hashes-without-access-to-pbkdf2-or-bcrypt/24933#24933)

Comment: Oh, didn't see that ! Thanks a lot ! And must the `iv` be the same for the two users ? I'm a bit confused. If I generate a new `iv` each time I encrypt a message, should I send the iv too ?

Comment: Yes, or derive the IV from something unique that you do send with the message, such as a message ID. (In fact, GCM accepts IVs of any size, so you can just use the message ID directly as the IV if you want.) Also, if two (or more) users are using the same key to encrypt messages, you'll need to [ensure that they don't use the same IVs](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/picking-a-nonce-in-the-context-of-ccm-ctr-with-cbc-mac-mode/29185#29185), e.g. by having one of them only use even IVs, and having the other use only odd IVs.

Comment: OK thanks. I think I'm gonna add a message ID on 2 bytes, that each increment (even/odd). Thanks again !